# Should I hoard keys for later, or spend them immediately?

Tags: blacksea-odyssey

In Blacksea Odyssey, you'll randomly get keys from the dismembered corpses of alien monsters you've hunted. There are, of course, various chests littered around the map, which have randomized treasure inside them.

I'm curious: do the later levels have better treasure? Or does every treasure chest have the same random equipment, and so I should spend keys just as fast as I find them? (Various levels have bonuses/penalties on the amount of things found in chests – but I want to know if chest quality *also* depends on the level.)